# Replace Table in HTML Dom Object

Tags: php

Is it possible to select table with specific bgcolor and replace it with new table?

$message is my DOM Object which contains an html newsletter having following table.

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
  some rows and columns
</table>
```

I want this to be replaced with $new_table where

```
$new_table = '<table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                new rows and columns
             </table>';
```

Comment: i can delete table by `$old_table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(3); $old_table->parentNode->removeChild($old_table);` but not sure how to replace it with $new_table

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the table and then use a jQuery selector to empty the table and add the new columns:

> ```
> <style>
> .backGroundGray{
>     background-color: #EEEEEE;
> }
>  </style>
>
> <table width="100%"  class="backGroundGray">
>     <tr>
>         <td>
>           some rows and columns
>         </td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
>
>
> <script>
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>
>      //Using jQuery
>      var new_table = '<table width="100%" class="backGroundGray"><tr><td>new rows and columns</td></tr></table>';
>
>     $('table.backGroundGray').empty().html(new_table);
>
> });
>
> </script>
> ```

Here's a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/7Zd9f/

Comment: yeah thank you for the help but unfortunately this is not loaded into browser. the table is in HTML DOM Object named $message.